# Declaring Dependencies from External File in Gradle

Tags: gradle, dependency-management, gradle-plugin

I'm looking for a way to enforce all dependency versions of subprojects in an external file in Gradle 5.2 or within the main build file. This would be similar to the new constraint functionality in the Java-Platform plugin, but, as far as I can tell, that requires declaration in not just a separate file but a separate project (which then would only house the build file for that project).

Is there a way to do this? So far I'm succesful in making a PoC with the java-platform plugin as such:

File Structure:

1. Root
   a. Platform
   b. Subproject 1
   c. Subproject 2

Root Build File:

```
project.ext {
    javaProjectList = subprojects.findAll{
        it.name != 'platform'
    }
}


configure(project.javaProjectList) {
    apply plugin: 'java'
}

subprojects{
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Platform Build File:

```
plugins {
    id 'java-platform'
}

dependencies {
    constraints {
        api 'commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:3.1'
        runtime 'org.postgresql:postgresql:42.2.5'
    }
}
```

Subproject 1 (and 2):

```
dependencies {
    compile platform(project(':platform'))
    compile 'commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient'
}
```

What I'd like is something along the lines of...

root/dependencies.versions:

```
dependency1.version1
dependency2.version3
{etc.}
```

root/build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    constraints {
        for { line in dependencies.versions -> 
            api 'line'
        }
    }
}
```

Please excuse the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a way to remove the requirement of a separate Platform project, but it was simple enough to read in the constraints via a properties file.